# File.Copy a file created in memory

Tags: c#

So I create this file:

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
TextWriter tw = new StreamWriter(ms);
tw.WriteLine("HELLO WORLD!");
tw.Flush();
byte[] bytes = ms.GetBuffer();
```

How can I use `File.Copy()` to, well, copy this file to a new file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [File.WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to create a new file (or overwrite an existing file) from a byte array:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(fileName, bytes);
```

Note that a MemoryStream (what you created) really isn't a "file", so `File.Copy` can't be used.

Answer (score 5):

Since you have your `bytes`, you can write them to a new file using [`File.WriteAllBytes`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
File.WriteAllBytes("path", bytes);
```

If the only matter is writing some text content to a file, I would recommend you to use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143375%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
File.WriteAllText("path", "HELLO WORLD");
```